# What is with the 'Chat with an Expert' popup I just started seeing on DA?

Tags: discussion, chat

The past couple of days, I have been getting an annoying, and seemingly random, popup on DA inviting me to 'Chat with an expert'. I finally broke down, and clicked on it. This was the conversation:

```
Expert: Hi, how can I be of assistance?

You: Just started getting this popup. Is this a new feature?

Expert: Well, this can be many things, including a new feature.

You: I am talking about the 'Chat with an expert' popup on DA

Expert: Oh really? I'm kind of talking about the 'chat with an expert' popup on da myself.
```

Am I missing something. I thought SE was trying NOT to become a social networking site. I have no idea what triggered this popup, but I am not impressed, particularly with the response I received.

Comment: April Fools "joke"...  Look at Meta.SO.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/april-fools

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was the joke for [April Fool's Day 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174407/what-is-chat-with-an-expert).  See also all of the activity on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/april-fools).  The Javascript for the bot is supposed to take into account the timezone on the user's local machine, so that it is only seen on 1 April 2013 localtime.

Comment: Javascript didn't work. Thanks for the explanation.